# File transfer speed over local network (WLAN) suddenly drops after while (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: samba, backup, rsync, lan, transfer

I'm trying to back up multiple files (around 1000 of them, 40 GB all) over WLAN from one computer to another.

Both computers run on Ubuntu 22.04.

I've tried multiple ways of copying files.

Sharing folder with samba, copying files via scp, using rsync. Basically, the method doesn't matter.

At the beginning, copying goes smoothly. Transfer speed depends on the method, but it's around what I expect (10 - 25 MB/s).

After a while (there's no hard time limit, it can be 1 minute it can be 15 minutes), transfer speed significantly drops to ~ 35 KB/s and stays on that level indefinitely (at least 30 minutes, I haven't waited longer).

After stopping copying and starting it again, speed goes back to normal, but after some time it drops again.

Both computers have 16 GB of RAM, decent CPUs, and shows a plenty of free resources while copying.

What can be the culprit?

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you transfer files using a USB flash drive or similar?

Comment: No, copying to external plugged in drives goes without any problems. Even more - copying to storage services like Backblaze or Google Drive also goes smoothly with full speed without the drop. It's also not a receiver laptop fault, because I checked sending data to two different devices (laptop and raspberry pi). In both cases, there's a drop in transfer speed after a while.